# Excel cell message to enter message based on another cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to put a message in all cells in column C where there is a value of either "Certification" or "Probity" in column F. For all other values in column F, I would like column C to be cleared of any information.

Comment: Is column C supposed to be editable as well, or is it just for display purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need?

> =IF(OR(F1="Certification",F1="Probity"), "Message","")

Replace Message with whatever your message is...

Comment: You don't need to say `=TRUE`.